# The equality condition of $||A||_p \leq \left[ \sum_{j=1}^m || A_{j\cdot}^T ||_q^p \right]^{1/p}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that the inequality below gets the equality
$$||A||_p \leq \left[ \sum_{j=1}^m || A_{j\cdot}^T ||_q^p  \right]^{1/p}$$
when $A$ is a rank 1 matrix.

Here $A\in\mathcal M(m,n)$ and $p, q$ are Hölder conjugates. $||\cdot||_p$
 is matrix $p$ norm.

The proof is
$$
\begin{align}
||A||_p
& = \max_{||x||_p=1} ||Ax||_p =
\max_{||x||_p=1} \left[ \sum_{j=1}^m | \sum_{k=1}^nA_{jk}x_k |^p \right]^{1/p} \\
& \overset{(*)}\leq \max_{||x||_p=1} \left[ \sum_{j=1}^m ||A_{j\cdot}^T||_q^p\cdot ||x||_p^p\right]^{1/p} \\
& = \left[ \sum_{j=1}^m || A_{j\cdot}^T ||_q^p  \right]^{1/p}
\end{align}
$$
and Hölder's inequality is used for every $j$-th row at $(*)$. By using the equality condition of Hölder's inequality,
$$
\lambda|x_k|^p = |a_{jk}|^q
$$
for all $k,\ j$ and constant $\lambda$. If $\lambda(x_k)^p =(a_{jk})^q$ holds then clearly all rows are mutually linearly dependent so the rank should be 1, but the absolute signs make me cannot go through.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.